# access attributes from two entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I created two entities and they have navigation properties.

```
 var list = from u in storeDB.Users
            join a in storeDB.Accounts
            on u.Id equals a.Id
            select new { u, a };
```

if I do a

```
foreach( user in list){
   <span>user.Name, user.Money</span>
}
```

It does not work. My question is how can I display the content from the result attributes of both tables, that is, of the join??

```
Users: has Name, Id
Accounts: has Id, Money
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using this in an MVC view so you need to create a view model for your combined user and account objects and send an Enumerable of it at the model.

```
public class UserAccountVM{
    public Account Acct { get; set; }
    public User Usr { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your query do this:

```
var list = from u in storeDB.Users            
           join a in storeDB.Accounts            
           on u.Id equals a.Id            
           select new UserAccountVM { Usr = u, Acct = a };
```

Pass the list as your model.  Your view should be strongly typed; `IEnumerable<UserAccountVM>` should work.  Then do this in your view:

```
foreach( user in list){   
    <span>user.Usr.Name, user.Acct.Money</span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties on the anonymous object are `u` and `a` as you've named them.  You probably want to give them better names or, better yet, simply select the properties you are interested in.  I would give them explicit names, but you could omit that if the names you want are the same as the property names and there aren't any conflicts.

```
var list = from u in storeDB.Users
           join a in storeDB.Accounts
           on u.Id equals a.Id
           select new { Name = u.Name, Money = a.Money };
```

Then use them as

```
foreach( user in list){
     <span>user.Name, user.Money</span>
}
```

Comment: I tried this before but it marks a server error  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Comment: @bb2 - Is this MVC (2 or 3)? or web forms?  If MVC what's the type of the model?  If you're using MVC2 you'll probably need a strongly typed view with a View-specific model that has the properties you want for the View.  Instead of selecting an anonymous object, select the View-specific model and set the properties from the your User/Account objects.

Comment: ASP MVC 3, yes I just read about this. I have to create a ViewModel, thanks!

Comment: @bb2 - MVC3 ought to be able to deal with a dynamic (anonymous type) view model if you're using the Razor view engine, but creating a strongly-typed one would be my preference, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [including the related objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx).

e.g.

```
var list = storeDB.Users.Include("Accounts");
```

Comment: This brings me to my other problem which I posted yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396648/how-does-include-work?tab=active#tab-top Because of this problem I am doing the join manually... =(